# Bootstrap popover with a link creates problem upon changing the resolution and zooming

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

In my project we use bootstrap and jquery, the popover function is used to display additional information about records.
The problem is the popover width is generated dynamically , so a column with longtext or varchar set to a high number uses the max-width of popover class i.e that's set 800px at the moment.The project here also has a nav bar , so upon having a record with lots of characters in it , the popover width is set to max and it glitches. The glitches are :-

1. Zooming in a lot , makes the link/popover flicker , i.e my cursor
   keeps changing , the popover comes and goes. Please note that code
   snippet linked below is without a nav bar so upon trying a bit , the
   popover displays correctly but not with in my project. So this makes
   impossible for me to click on the link attached. The cursor just
   keeps changing.

[image: flicker]

2. Changing screen size to a phone ( pixel 2 ) or tablet ( ipad pro) , sets the popover function to on click from on hover , was fine on my previous bootstrap file ie the popover displayed onclick for a second then the link opened. But Like i said before when the width of a column is alot it creates an issue.Over here the issue is the popover does not get displayed on clicking the element , nor does why link work.

[image: glitch2]

The code snippet link is [code pen](https://codepen.io/craigkrodrigues/pen/PooQVLK)

The files used:-
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFU_jaHwZk3anw2wwRK7DKyaM0VKQ8hz`
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=17G9a6LE-x3MRcIsP2FuBsoxJ66NJE-Rs`
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L6BcD_-90S2twjJXv7FXI9655DN_aMbx`
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AMdOYQ878b_CEANGUWAjqOoP6bwpT_t5`
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=10eJw0JvGMrDLLH07D9ABxVu9YMaOCBf3`

I need to know how to make the popover displayed onclick for a second then the link opened for phone/tablet and solve the first glitch.